# Besides "Chicken TV" does this type of food have any other names?

Tags: food

A [English tutorial](https://youtu.be/UUUJCmtDoZ8?t=25) calls this type of food "Chicken TV".

[image]

However, [googling with "Chicken TV"](https://www.google.com/search?q=chicken%20tv) doesn't give any results related.

Besides "Chicken TV" does this type of food have any other names?

Comment: I first thought you mean [*TV Dinner*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frozen_meal), brought to my attention in the 1980s by John Lurie in Jim Jarmusch's *Stranger Than Paradise* ([here](https://youtu.be/MwefGellnhk?t=35) is the scene). But Michael's answer is correct. While these chickens are industrial food in the wider sense they are not pre-packaged entire meals, nor are they deepfrozen.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That food isn't called "Chicken TV". It's called 'roast chicken', or sometimes 'rotisserie chicken'. What you saw is a 'rotisserie oven' or 'rotary oven' used for roasting chickens for sale as hot cooked food. The glass window seems to remind some people of a TV screen so the speaker on the video made a joke.

Comment: They are common in France. I was in Nice one summer years ago, and the smell made me buy a whole small chicken for around the equivalent of $2 and took it back to the hotel. The smell may have been tempting, but the reality was a greasy horror.

Comment: the word "rotisserie" is also just about visible in the linked video a couple of times as the frame bobs up. I agree that "Chicken TV" is intended as a joke here, but it may be worth noting that it will be a reference to the cabinet as a whole rather than the food within it

Comment: @Tristan - I think that arguably 'chicken TV' could be a reference to the type of programme being seen on the imagined TV, just as if you saw dolphins, snakes, lions, in a show on a TV you might call that 'wildlife TV'.

Comment: might be a coincidence, but the name of the youtube channel is "LetThemTalkTV". maybe there's also a channel meme going on or they were just playing off of that, though I agree that the joke works regardless.

Comment: @Tristan I could also still see the joke working as "Chicken [from a] TV", mimicking Chicken Kiev, chicken paprikash, and other chicken dishes that follow the form _chicken [loose adjective]_, though your interpretation and Michael's seem the most likely. English, amirite

Comment: This is, arguably, audio by a YouTube dweeb with verbal diarrhoea, not great English.